# Deviance residual plot abnormal for Cox proportional model

Tags: survival, cox-model, proportional-hazards

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is the cox proportion hazard model violated? I'm not sure whether the problem is censored data or wrong prediction?

But, there is only few significant variables can fit the hazard model adequately. I'm very fresh on survival analysis. Anyone can share your experiences?

Answer (score 1):

The critical test is `cox.zph(tt1)`, in which neither of the individual predictors nor the Global model shows a significant deviation from proportional hazards (PH): all p-values are quite large. So there's no sign of a violation of PH in this model.

The plots you have shown aren't very useful for evaluating PH, however.

First, they are plots of residuals against observation numbers. If you are evaluating PH, the question is whether hazard ratios are constant over time. For PH evaluation, plots against some function of time are better.

Second, neither of the type of residual you show is suited to that purpose.

Deviance residuals can have some benefit in showing outliers, but don't directly help evaluate PH. The related martingale residuals can be used for evaluating the functional form of a continuous predictor, which if improperly specified can lead to an apparent violation of PH, but those plots would then be done against the predictor values, not against observation numbers.

The Schoenfeld residuals do form the basis of the PH test performed by `cox.zph()`, but not in their unscaled form (which I think is what you have plotted). They need to be *scaled* inversely with respect to the corresponding variance estimate of the coefficient at the event time.

The most useful plots are produced from commands like `plot(cox.zph(tt1))`; those show the scaled Schoenfeld residuals plotted against a useful default Kaplan-Meier transformation of time (which you can override with another transformation of time if you wish) and a smoothed curve illustrating trends over time. It's often simplest to save the output from `cox.zph()` in a named object and do the plotting on that, follwing the manual's instructions for subscripting to get plots for each coefficient.